# Basic iptables implementation

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am new to iptables and I have been doing Google searches for a few days now without finding a good solution to this problem.

I have computer A with a public ip address 5.6.7.8 that can access the Internet unrestricted. I have another computer B with a private ip address 1.2.3.4 that can only access computer A. How do I use iptables to forward network traffic from B through A to the Internet? I need to use http, ftp, and https in order to use apt-get with sudo.

Both computers run Ubuntu linux. I have tried using Squid but I think it is far too complicated for what I need to do.

(These are obviously not the real ip addresses but I've noticed that the general Internet explanations are unreadable without understanding the setup of the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming machine A has two network interfaces, say eth0 and eth1. Interface eth1 (external) is conected to the modem, and eth0 (internal) is conected to a switch or direct to machine B.

First you need to enable packet forwarding in machine A:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Now you can save the following as /etc/init.d/fwscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
  ipt=/sbin/iptables
  extip=5.6.7.8   # replace with your EXTERNAL IP
  lan=192.168.0.0/24 # your LAN

  # start firewall
  start_firwall {
    echo "Enabling iptables firewall."
    # default policies
    $ipt -P INPUT DROP
    $ipt -P FORWARD DROP

    # NAT
    $ipt -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source $extip

    # INPUT chain
    $ipt -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    $ipt -A INPUT -i eth1 -s $lan -j ACCEPT
    $ipt -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    $ipt -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j ACCEPT

    # FORWARD chain
    $ipt -A FORWARD -i eth1 -s $lan -j ACCEPT
    $ipt -A FORWARD -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
  }

  # stop firewall
  stop_firwall {
    $ipt -P INPUT DROP
    $ipt -P OUTPUT DROP
    $ipt -P FORWARD DROP
    # allow internal traffic
    $ipt -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
    $ipt -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
  }

  # flushing, removing and zeroing tables

  reset_firewall {
    chains=`cat /proc/net/ip_tables_names`
    for i in $chains; do
      $debug $ipt -t $i -F
      $debug $ipt -t $i -X
      $debug $ipt -t $i -Z
    done
  }

  case "$1" in
    start|restart|reload)
      reset_firewall
      start_firewall
      ;;
    stop)
      reset_firewall
      stop_firewall
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload}"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  exit 0
```

The script must be executable (chmod +x fwscript.sh). Now you can run it simply by typing: ./fwscript.sh [start|stop].
Now to get your firewall running at startup:

```
update-rc.d fwscript.sh defaults 99
```

You only need squid if you want to monitor traffic or cache. But squid configuration requires some changes in fwscript.sh, and you need to decide if you want transparent or not transparent proxy.
I'd try without squid for now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I do need some clarification on your answer though. Does the script go on machine B or machine A? If it is on machine A, what do I need to do to B? Machine A only has 1 network interface. Is this a problem?

Comment: The script goes on machine A, which is going to be your gateway. Yes, machine A needs two network interfaces to do the forwarding.

Comment: I'm also assuming you already have a communication between A and B, through static IPs or DHCP. You can configure your machine A to be a DHCP server also, and B will get dynamic IP from A (with dhcpclient).

Comment: I do already have communication between A and B but B is on a different subnet and has a static IP so I don't know how B would know to route through A.

Comment: You can configure static IP from B to know A as his gateway and nameserver. In B, edit /etc/network/interfaces and put:

    iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.10 # internal address of B
        network 192.168.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.254 # internal address of A

Also, edit /etc/resolv.conf:

    nameserver 192.168.1.254 # internal address of A
    nameserver 8.8.8.8